# Google App Engine Payment Gateway Dynamic IP address requirement

Tags: google-app-engine, payment-gateway, opayo

I know this question has been asked in various ways but has anyone successfully integrated a payment gateway for GAE in JAVA in the UK?

I've looked at Stripe (US only), PayPal, Google Checkout and more recently SagePay.

I made some good progress with the SagePay for Java API but am thwarted by the whitelist requirement for a static IP address.  Given all cloud computing services seem to operate on dynamic IP address assignment this seems a show-stopper for not only GAE but also other cloud services.

I've contacted SagePay and they can only work with a static IP unless using Form based integration but I want to keep users on my site and have as much control over the look and feel and user experience as possible.

Does anyone have any suggestions or has looked into this themselves?

In my experience offering only paypal or google checkout options results in loss of customers as people don't want to be bothered by creating accounts and often (in the example of paypal) miss the small print explaining sign-up is not required.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I use a reverse proxy (with a fixed ip) to access the payment provider. In my case: Ogone directlink. I did not find a public free service. So i created a small program which runs on a webserver with a fixed IP.